# problem with signing from ledger account

Tags: signing

When I try to sign a refund, I have following error :

Error
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"fonteintjeos","permission":"owner"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [], provided keys ["EOS5bmjRPgLbTA43qwvi7mtLJVmFJ12fVSJzT7WysKqHfNc8XeCdT","EOS88o6GYDXU2wntsS4c7h9dmUuXJe4ZBp7x98Lu5MgdimLqEafzo"], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms

can anybody tell me how I can solve this problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fonteintjeos` account has the public key `EOS7FarQQ13Dqn6Etc8me5ZYmsG9F8t8yDu5dPd1GouMYB8xHbWWZ` for its owner and active permission.

Your error message shows ledger provides the next keys, but not that of your account:
`EOS5bmjRPgLbTA43qwvi7mtLJVmFJ12fVSJzT7WysKqHfNc8XeCdT`
`EOS88o6GYDXU2wntsS4c7h9dmUuXJe4ZBp7x98Lu5MgdimLqEafzo`

What key did you use to create account? It seems that your key hasn't been changed since account creation.

Comment: I don't know this anymore.  I created it some years ago and I don't think I have changed it.  How can I solve this ?

Comment: You can try searching for the key matched to your account from ledger, if you can't, it seems not possible to recover your key.

Comment: so to look for the keys matched to EOS5bmjRPgLbTA43qwvi7mtLJVmFJ12fVSJzT7WysKqHfNc8XeCdT EOS88o6GYDXU2wntsS4c7h9dmUuXJe4ZBp7x98Lu5MgdimLqEafzo ?